# How to get values from one table column, concatenate them with a string and insert them in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

How to:

1. Get values from table1.column1 (e.g. abc)

   `table1.column1=abc`
2. Concatenate them with certain fixed strings, e.g.

   `xxx
   yyy
   zzz`
3. Insert the results as separate rows in table2.column2. The final result should be rows with values like this:

   `table2.column2=abc_xxx
   table2.column2=abc_yyy
   table2.column2=abc_zzz`

(table2 has a connecting column indicating to which ID the table2.column2 record corresponds in case this matters)

4. Repeat this process for all records in **table1.column1** which have **table1.item_id > 100**

**EDIT**: For certain convenience I would like the final result rows sequence to look like:

`source1_xxx
source1_yyy
source1_zzz
source2_xxx
source2_yyy
source2_zzz`

and not like:

`source1_xxx
source2_xxx
source1_yyy
source2_yyy
source1_zzz
source2_zzz`

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do this in one query. You would either need to do multiple queries on the server side or use a transaction.

Comment: It's ok to use several queries. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is the server side language?

Comment: The server is Percona (mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want N (e.g. 3) entries for every existing row in Table1. If so, you can CROSS JOIN Table1 to a projection of the values, like so:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(column2)
    SELECT CONCAT(t1.column1, '_', x.col)
    FROM Table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 'xxx' AS col
     UNION
     SELECT 'yyy'
     UNION 
     SELECT 'zzz') x;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b526/1)

**Edit**

The query was updated to be cognaisant of the ordering and filtering requirements as well:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(column2)
    SELECT CONCAT(t1.column1, '_', x.col)
    FROM Table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT 'xxx' AS col
     UNION
     SELECT 'yyy'
     UNION 
     SELECT 'zzz') x
    WHERE t1.ID > 100
    ORDER BY t1.column1 ASC, x.col ASC;
```

[With an updated SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be7b/1)

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Could you please have a look at the edit too? I tried what you suggest but it seems to give the other sequence, not the one I need: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2a3d8/1)

Comment: MySql allows you to order by during the insert which will sequence correctly when used e.g. with an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Does this [updated fiddle help?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcfed/1)

Comment: This looks better :) Before trying it on the server - could you just tell me how to modify it so that it affects only table1.item_id>100? I.e. where do I put the 'where' condition. Thanks!

Comment: `WHERE` goes after `FROM` and before `ORDER BY`. Another [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be7b/1)

Comment: Awesome. Please let me try that on the server and I will get back to confirm that this is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the answer.

Credit goes to the StuartLC ..he is right, you would need to use cross join

```
INSERT INTO Table2(column2)
SELECT CONCAT(t1.column1, '_', x.col)
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT 'xxx' AS col
 UNION
 SELECT 'yyy'
 UNION 
 SELECT 'zzz') x;
```

Comment: I suppose that would create a row sequence in table2 like:

    `source1_xxx
source2_xxx
source1_yyy
source2_yyy
source1_zzz
source2_zzz`

For certain convenience I would rather want the rows values to be sequenced like this:

    `source1_xxx
source1_yyy
source1_zzz
source2_xxx
source2_yyy
source2_zzz`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

is this what u want

```
 insert into table2(column2)
 select concat(col1,'_','xxx') from table1
 union

 select concat(1col1,'_','yyy') from table1

union 

 select concat(col1,'_','zzz') from table1
```

else keep this entire select statemnts in aview and use it in the insert statement

```
create view abc 
as
 select concat(col1,'_','xxx') from table1
     union

     select concat(1col1,'_','yyy') from table1

    union 

     select concat(col1,'_','zzz') from table1
```

then

```
  insert into table2(column2) select * from abc
```

Comment: This won't work on MySQL.  You need `INSERT INTO...VALUES (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9)`